# how do I create a stored procedure from within a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to manage the deploy of stored procedures by first inserting them into a table, then, when it's time to deploy.... use a stored procedure to create all of the stored procedures. (Execute seems to be limited to CRUD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with MySQL. In stored procedures and functions you have even more restrictions in language use then in prepared statements.

The list of acceptable commands for prepared statements (see [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)) does not include `create procedure`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you looking for, but its has a good example and a reference at the bottom.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,219523,219787#msg-219787

Matthew H.